# Computer Shuts Down Unexpectedly After 24-48hrs of Uptime

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

For quite some time now, my desktop (which runs 24/7 generally) will shut down after around 24-48 hours of running. As far as I can tell, nothing in particular is forcing the shut down. After taking a look at Event Viewer, there are a couple of events that occur at the time of shutdown consistently. However, I am not sure if these events are the cause of the shutdown or the result of an unexpected shutdown. The associated Event Viewer Logs can be seen below.

[Event Viewer Log 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GeNtZ8-G_VGQPMrwWi98CToLMigD1zaq)

[Event Viewer Log 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sed9FlZ57vc24p3PSUAffY9QR7ueQ-6r)

OVRServiceLauncher seems to consistently throw an error (accompanied by warnings), all of which are associated with an Oculus Rift runtime. Though I'm unsure if this is a cause of effect.

As far as I can tell, there are no overheating issues or hardware failures.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to remove or update the Oculus Rift runtime?

Comment: I have tried disabling the Oculus VR Runtime Service to no avail so far.

Comment: Sometimes disabling isn't enough, I also asked if you had tried to **uninstall it**.  You should also try updating it.

Comment: I noticed that you are running of trace buffers when this happens. Try to start *Perfmon → Data Collector Sets → Startup Event Trace Session → right click Defender API Logger → Properties*, in the *Trace Session* tab change *Stream Mode* to *File and Real Time*, in the *File* tab under *Log Mode* tick *Circular*, finally click OK. Undo if it doesn't work.